# 3 home routers and 2 ISPs

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have the following situation.

[image]

And I am on R3. How can I make for everyone in R3 to gain access to R1?

Comment: Any information on distances? I mean is it possible to set it up like R1 and R2?

Comment: @Cown what do you mean? Same building ..

Comment: If it's within reach, can't you connect R3 to R1 as you've done with R2?

Comment: Does at least one of the routers support reconfiguring ports such that you'd have a third network in addition to "WAN" and "LAN"? (Possibly in VLAN section.)

Comment: Now that I think of it, why are R1 and R2 using different subnets?... (If that's not necessary,

Answer (score 1):

1. Connect R1 and R3 with a cable.
2. Make sure the DHCP is disabled on R3.
3. Configure R3 LAN interface so it has an address from 192.168.1/24 subnet.
4. Assign static IPs to the R3 hosts, so they have addresses from 192.168.1/24, but a default gateway and DNS pointing to R3.